# Wordpress menu: automatically add categories

Tags: wordpress, menuitem

In Wordpress, i'd like to automatically add  categories from custom post types in a submenu item, with respecting the hierarchy.

This is how my menu will look like:

- Projects

  - Categories

    - Category 1
    - Category 2

      - Subcategory1
      - Subcategory2
    - Category 3
    - ....
  - Other Sub item

    - ItemX
    - ItemY

Any idea on how to automatically add all categories in the menu, under "Categories" item?
(It's a menu created in Appearance > Menus)
I guess i might use [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) but I have no idea where to place this...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try this filter

It's a little hacky but i managed to add some stuff into my menus from here

[WP nav menu itmes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items)

```
function wp_nav_menu_items( $items, $args ) {
    if ( "primary" == $args->theme_location ) { //check what menu it is
        //Do Stuff here
    }

    return $itmes;
}

add_filter( wp_nav_menu_items, wp_nav_menu_items );
```

Comment: Thanks, it does indeed add a new item, but at top level.
I'd like to add these items under a specific menu item.

Comment: Well you just got to mod the $items a little more, strpos the right spot, or just str_replace them in there